# Can't open keycharmap file

Tags: android, menu

what's the keycharmap file??
when i press the back botton of my device Android it doesn't go back and i get this warning:

```
08-27 15:46:33.953: W/KeyCharacterMap(19073): Can't open keycharmap file
08-27 15:46:33.953: W/KeyCharacterMap(19073): Error loading keycharmap file
08-27 15:46:33.953: W/KeyCharacterMap(19073): Using default keymap
```

this problem when i added this method:

```
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
         //do something
            return true;
        } else {
            return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
        }
    }
```

can any one help me to complete this method to do something and go back? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you should change your code to this:

```
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) 
        {
            //do something                
        } 

        //this line must be run for handle back key!  
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);       
}
```